# Why did lieutenant Kellaway remain unaffected by Cuban Pete's dance?

Tags: the-mask

When Stanley Ipkiss as The Mask flees out of Landfill Park, he is confronted by a sizable police force. He then breaks out in singing "Cuban Pete", engaging the entire police force, sometimes visibly against their own better judgement and to their own surprise.

After lieutenant Kellaway and detective Doyle climb down from the wall around Landfill Park, Doyle is affected as well and starts dancing until stopped by Kellaway, who then proceeds to tell other police officers to "snap out if it!"

But why wasn't Kellaway affected?

Comment: I got the impression that Doyle was joining in on his own rather than any affect the Mask may be having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [draft version of the script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Mask,-The.html) available online. It doesn't quite have the sequence of events in the same order as the film but it's accurate enough to be a mostly trustworthy source of information and also matches my reading of the scene.

The main points of interest are:

> Stanley/Mask SWAYS seductively in time to the music.
>
> [...]
>
> The cops watch this with open mouthed astonishment.
>
> [...]
>
> Like some weird, loony case of mass hypnosis, Stanley/Mask waits for the "musical break" to coax the armed cops into JOINING him on the number - as the rough and tumble equivalent of CHORUS GIRLS!
>
> [...]
>
> The street takes the look of a Busby Berkeley musical as the cops HIGH STEP in time to the infectious RUMBA beat.
>
> [...]
>
> Doyle crash lands beside Kellaway and starts out to join the
> others, but Kellaway grabs him by the back of his jacket.
>
> [...]
>
> Furious, Kellaway yanks open the door of an abandoned squad car, pulls out a tear gas gun and fires into the air. The sharp REPORT AND stinging gas seems to break the spell of THE MASK. The music suddenly STOPS and the high stepping cops stagger away from the CHORUS line, looking confused.
>
> <sub>*The Mask* draft script</sub>

All of the above seems to imply that the affect of the music and what the Mask is doing takes some time to take affect of the people watching. In the scene we see how only one cop really gets taken a hold straightaway until those around him snap him out of it. The rest all keep doing their jobs until they all get under the spell at the same time.

Doyle by contrast doesn't really join in with the dance like everyone else and is doing his own silly moves. The draft script also doesn't mention him joining in similar to how it does with the others so it seems he really just joins in on his own. Which largely fits with the silly comedic character he is meant to be.

So, it's not really that Kellaway remains unaffected, it's that everyone remains unaffected until the Mask wants them to be affected. The woman coaxed into singing only does so when the Mask makes a comedic wave of the fingers at her like he's mind controlling her and the rest only when he coaxes them into joining him. Kellaway and Doyle just hadn't been targeted to join in yet and any chance of that is cut short when Kellaway fires the tear gas and snaps everyone else out of it.